# Запись битов в цветовой канал пикселя

Tags: java, битовые-операции

Беру красную составляющую цвета таким образом:

```
int clr = needlePixels[i];
int red = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
```

Затем произвожу некоторые действия над битами переменной `red`. Как записать измененную составляющую цвета обратно в переменную `clr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clr = (clr & 0xFF00FFFF) | (red << 16)
```

Например так (если не напутал). Сбрасываем целевые биты и потом устанавливаем их из red.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает.